# Why sometimes i'm getting exception indexOutOfRange?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is a timer tick event inside i'm getting each process memory usage.
In 95% of the time even more it's working fine i tried like 20 times run my program until the exception throw up.

In the top of the form:

```
System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
```

Then in the constructor:

```
aTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
aTimer.Interval = 1000;
```

Then the timer elapsed event:

```
Image ima = null;
        private void OnTimedEvent(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<MyProgress> prog = new List<MyProgress>();

            prog = new List<MyProgress>();
            DoubleBufferedd(dataGridView1, true);
            procList = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < procList.Count; i++)
            {
                Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(procList[i].ProcessName);
                PerformanceCounter performanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
                performanceCounter.CategoryName = "Process";
                performanceCounter.CounterName = "Working Set - Private";
                performanceCounter.InstanceName = processes[0].ProcessName;
                try
                {
                    var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(processes[0].MainModule.FileName);
                    ima = icon.ToBitmap();
                    ima = resizeImage(ima, new Size(25, 25));
                    ima = (Image)(new Bitmap(ima, new Size(25, 25)));
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                prog.Add(new MyProgress { Id = procList[i].Id, Progress = ((uint)performanceCounter.NextValue() / 1024).ToString("N0"), ProcImage = ima, ProcessName = procList[i].ProcessName });


            }
            BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
            List<MyProgress> list = prog;//new List<MyProgress>();



                foreach (MyProgress p in list)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row;

                    if (!processRows.TryGetValue(p.Id, out row))
                    {
                        int index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(p.ProcImage, p.ProcessName, null, p.Progress);
                        row = dataGridView1.Rows[index];
                        processRows.Add(p.Id, row);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.Cells[3].Value = p.Progress;
                    }
                }
                foreach (int id in processRows.Keys.Except(list.Select(p => p.Id)).ToArray())
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(processRows[id]);
                    processRows.Remove(id);
                }
            }));
        }
```

When the exception happen then it's on the line:

```
 performanceCounter.InstanceName = processes[0].ProcessName;
```

> An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in
>   Automation.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array
>
> System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code

And it happen only once to many times. Most of the time the exception is not showing.

When i put the mouse on proclist then on Count i see:

> Count = Function evaluation disabled because a previous function
>   evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function
>   evaluation.

The interval of the timer is set to 1000ms.

Not sure what does it mean i must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. And how to fix it.
And why sometimes it does make the exception and in most of the cases not ?

I changed my code according to Dan answer but getting exception now in another place.
This is the new code:

```
Image ima = null;
        private void OnTimedEvent(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<MyProgress> prog = new List<MyProgress>();

            prog = new List<MyProgress>();
            DoubleBufferedd(dataGridView1, true);
            procList = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < procList.Count; i++)
            {
                                PerformanceCounter performanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
                performanceCounter.CategoryName = "Process";
                performanceCounter.CounterName = "Working Set - Private";//"Working Set";
                performanceCounter.InstanceName = procList[i].ProcessName;
                try
                {
                    var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(procList[i].MainModule.FileName);
                    ima = icon.ToBitmap();
                    ima = resizeImage(ima, new Size(25, 25));
                    ima = (Image)(new Bitmap(ima, new Size(25, 25)));
                }
                catch
                {

                }
                prog.Add(new MyProgress { Id = procList[i].Id, Progress = ((uint)performanceCounter.NextValue() / 1024).ToString("N0"), ProcImage = ima, ProcessName = procList[i].ProcessName });


            }
            BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
            List<MyProgress> list = prog;



                foreach (MyProgress p in list)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row;

                    if (!processRows.TryGetValue(p.Id, out row))
                    {
                                                int index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(p.ProcImage, p.ProcessName, null, p.Progress);
                        row = dataGridView1.Rows[index];
                        processRows.Add(p.Id, row);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.Cells[3].Value = p.Progress;
                    }
                }
                foreach (int id in processRows.Keys.Except(list.Select(p => p.Id)).ToArray())
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(processRows[id]);
                    processRows.Remove(id);
                }
            }));
        }
```

I'm not using any more the Process[] processes.

And changed the two lines to use the procList:

This line i'm using procList[I]

```
performanceCounter.InstanceName = procList[i].ProcessName;
```

And also this line i'm using procList[I]

```
var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(procList[i].MainModule.FileName);
```

But now i'm getting exception on the line:

```
prog.Add(new MyProgress { Id = procList[i].Id, Progress = ((uint)performanceCounter.NextValue() / 1024).ToString("N0"), ProcImage = ima, ProcessName = procList[i].ProcessName });
```

InvalidOperationException

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Instance 'SearchFilterHost' does not exist in the specified Category.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Instance 'SearchFilterHost' does not exist in the specified Category.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Diagnostics.CounterDefinitionSample.GetInstanceValue(String instanceName)
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.NextSample()
       at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.NextValue()
       at Automation.Form1.OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\Automation\Automation\Automation\Form1.cs:line 805
       at System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(Object state)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: you are likely hitting a threading issue.

Comment: you can use the [Debugger](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging) to get a better idea of what's happening

Comment: `Process.GetProcessesByName` might be returning an empty array and the index `0` is out of range.

Comment: Don't assume that processes[0] exists and you won't get the exception.

Comment: `IndexOutOfRangeException` happens when you go outside the bounds of an array. For example, if you have an array with 3 objects, and you try to call `ArrayName[4]`, you'll get that error. Set a breakpoint and find out why the code isn't working. Is the array getting filled? No, then it will be outside the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the three important lines of code in relation to your problem:

```
procList = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(procList[i].ProcessName);
performanceCounter.InstanceName = processes[0].ProcessName;
```

What you're doing here is

1. get a list of all processes
2. get a list of processes with the same name as one of the processes in the first list
3. get the name of the first process in the second list

Ignoring the redundancy here, the issue is one of timing.

Assume you have a process `foo.exe` running. That process appears in step 1's list. If that process should terminate between steps 1 and 2, your list at step 2 for `foo.exe` will be empty. Calling `processes[0]` when the list is empty will throw the exception you've seen.

To avoid this, I'd suggest you avoid step 2 entirely: you've already retrieved the information for all processes, so use the data you already have. This will have the likely benefit of speeding your code up!

Comment: Dan I changed my code I removed the line Process[] processes as step 2 not using it now. Then in the next lines in two places the line with the instancename = I did procList[i].ProcessName and also in the line with the icon extract procList[i].MainModule.FileName but now i'm getting another exception.

Comment: Dan I also updated my question with the changes I did and the exception i'm getting now.

Comment: @ManuelSpechia: your update changes the meaning/content of the question such that the existing answers are no longer relevant. You should revert your edit (in order to preserve the existing question) and then post the new issue as a separate question. As a suggestion for fixing the new problem, though: break that line down. You are calling several methods and it's not clear which is throwing the exception, so call each method on a separate line (using extra local variables to store results) and you can narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible there are no processes that have the name you are looking for. When that happens, `processes` will have a length of 0, and there are no valid indices. So no matter what number you put in the brackets, you will get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

To fix this, you should make sure there are matching processes before using the `processes` array:

```
//...
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(procList[i].ProcessName);
if (processes.Length > 0) {
    // ...
    performanceCounter.InstanceName = processes[0].ProcessName;
```

There's a handful of other ways to accomplish that goal, but this should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

During your loop if a process ends an exception will be thrown...